# Reset/Delete (not empty) product customization fields on Prestashop

Tags: prestashop, customization, custom-fields

I'm trying to reset the customization fields of a specific product on a Prestashop website.

Currently, i succeed in saving them, but when i visit other pages of my website and come back to this product page, the customization fields are still saved and displayed (which is the normal behavior, which is the normal behavior, i know).

My aim is to give the user a "Reset customization" button that really reset/delete the data and not just empty them temporarily (while you stay on the page)...

Is there a simple way to do this ?

Answer (score -1):

If I had to add a "Reset customization" button, here is how I would code it :

1. Add the button in your product.tpl file. In the 
   `<form>` div of the `<!--Customization -->` section

   ```
   <button class="button btn btn-default button button-small" name="resetCustomization" value="1">
       <span>{l s='Reset customization'}</span>
   </button>
   ```
2. Override the `initContent()` function from `ProductController.php` like so

   ```
   public function initContent()
   {
       if (Tools::isSubmit('resetCustomization')) {
           $this->product->deleteCustomization();
       }

       parent::initContent();
   }
   ```

Don't forget to make backups copy of these files and delete your `class_index.php` located in the /cache/ folder.